# Wordpress: Admin is not redirecting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is what I have in my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

However, when I navigate to the [admin side of my website](http://getincink.com/wp-admin), it does not redirect correctly and reappends the website address at the end of the URL.

This has also caused my [featured images](http://www.getincink.com/individuals/why-cink/) to disappear too.

Any clue what might be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `http://` in the beginning of the URL's

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29